# Apple Push Notification for Enterprise App Security Issue

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am working on an enterprise application to be distributed in-hously. As a feasibility study, I have read & have developed push notifications using APNS. Here is something I want to ask regaring APNS.

My humble request to.enthusiastic developers,

*"Answer this if they have encountered or have any idea or have done some sort of work like this. Please do not just point to any arbitrary tutorial or question links of Stack Overflow."*

1. What are the security aspects involded (from information security point of view) on the PayLoad that I will be sending to APNS server. My client cares because of the information Security policies that I too have to abide.
2. Is it possible to send / receive notification from the APNS from being within a VPN. How ?
3. Is it possible to completely bypass the APNS server & have a one in-house server, that can send notification to my device directly. How ?
4. What if, if I want to implement APNS but do not want to share my
   payload with APNS server.?

Thank you for reading my question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Although end points of the APNS architecture are TLS encrypted, Apple may see your data in clear text. You have to clarify with your customer, if this is ok or not.
2. Yes, but you'll need some [open ports](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4264)
3. No, this is not possible
4. You may use some kind of token as the payload and request the confidential information from your own server using this token.

Comment: If the client (android device/ios device) could setup a static IP using dynamic DNS solutions, wouldn't you then be able to send push notifications? Assuming there was a service running in the background.